# Passing parameter to Telerik Report

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, telerik-reporting

I have a telerik report project added to my website and I'm trying to pass a parameter to it but I receive the following error

> Error:
>
> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Asp.net Code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        MembershipCard rpt = new MembershipCard();
        // Error occuring here
        rpt.ReportParameters["@MemberID"].Value = "5"; // Request["MemberID"];
        ReportViewer1.Report = rpt;
    }        
}
```

Telerik Report Class

```
    public MembershipCard()
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required for telerik Reporting designer support
        /// </summary>
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataSource = null;
    }

    private void MembershipCard_NeedDataSource(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string proc = "rpt_MembershipCard" + this.ReportParameters["@MemberID"].Value.ToString();
        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(proc, "Data Source=(local); Initial Catalog= northwind; intergrated security = True");
        DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
        adapter.Fill(dataSet);
        (sender as Telerik.Reporting.Processing.Report).DataSource = dataSet;
    }
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction I haven't been able to find anything relevant on the internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is that you are not providing parameters. Try changing:

```
rpt.ReportParameters.Add("MemberID", "5");
```

And:

```
string proc = this.ReportParameters["MemberID"].Value.ToString();
```

Also, if you added `DataSet.xsd` file in the solution, use its generated `TableAdapter`.

Example for stored procedure:

```
using System.Data;
using YourNamespace.StoredProcedureNameTableAdapter;

//Keep in mind StoredProcedureName is taken from SP name in your database
//when you add DataSet.xsd to your solution by default if you don't change anything

private void ClassName_NeedDataSource(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   int someID = int.Parse(this.ReportParameters["ParameterID"].Value.ToString());
   StoredProcedureNameTableAdapter adapter = new StoredProcedureNameTableAdapter();
   DataSetFile.StoredProcedureNameDataTable data = adapter.GetData(someID); //DataSetFile is DataSetFile.xsd and GetData is method name you defined on DataSetFile.xsd creation
   ((Telerik.Reporting.Processing.Report)sender).DataSource = data.AsDataView();
}
```

Comment: When I try your suggestion I get the error 'rpt_PrintMembershipCard' does not contain a definition for 'ReportParameters' and no extension method 'ReportParameters' accepting a first argument of type 'rpt_PrintMembershipCard' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @Wellie Is the rpt_PrintMembershipCard name of the report you created? You should have rpt_PrintMembershipCard.cs file.
Your class definition should be:
`public partial class rpt_PrintMembershipCard : Telerik.Reporting.Report`

Comment: the .cs file is MembershipCard.cs and the web page that the report viewer is in is rpt_PrintMembershipCard

Comment: First code block is what you write in the ASP.NET page code. Keep in mind that `rpt` is same reference you used in your code.
Other 2 blocks are written in the report code sections.
Can you copy the line that is giving you exception?

Comment: the exception is being thrown here  <code> rpt.ReportParameters["@MemberID"].Value = "5";'</code> but it turns out that I was missing the @ in declaring the parameter